# Modifying two Select at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, I've managed to make it work after some fail and retry, but I don't understand why some of my try failed.  :
My goal was to modify two select depending on some informations in the page (the 2 select are supposed to be filled with the same informations)

Fail attempt 2 I don't understand  :

```
$('#select1').find('option').remove().end();
$('#select2').find('option').remove().end();

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement('option')
    option.value = data[i].value;
    option.text = data[i].text;
    $('#select2').append(option);
    $('#select1').append(option);
```

this empty both of my select, but only the `#select1` is filled afterward. If I swap the two last lines -->

Fail attempt 1 I don't understand  :

```
    $('#select1').append(option);
    $('#select2').append(option);
```

Now it's my `#select2` that is filled.

And to make it work I had to do `$('#select1, #select2').append(option);`

Why the two first try failed ? was the `var option = document.createElement('option')`
 like a python generator?

EDIT : **My issue isn't about the #, I forgot to type them in the question, but they were present in my code**

Comment: It seems they failed because you missed the `#`. You need to add `#` here `$('select1').`

Comment: fixed in the question. (I typed all the code, copy/pasta  the code isn't possible) This time I typed it right

Comment: Make a working snippet

Comment: @TylerKirby thanks ! that was exactly what i was looking for. (Sad I couldn't find it on my own though)

Comment: @pwnsauce You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this behaviour is that the `document.createElement` returns an HTML element, which is a real object, and you can append it to any other element in your HTML as much times as you want.

But since, its the same object, it is not cloned when you append it to the second dropdown. You can call `.cloneNode` to make a copy of it, and then append it:

```
$('#select1').append(option);
$('#select2').append(option.cloneNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors don't include the #:

```
 $('#select1').append(option);  
 $('#select2').append(option);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot them  (can't copy/paste my code) but it wasn't the problem